# Linear Algebra Confusion!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

is the set of all upper triangular matrices a vector space?

I have tried to research if it's a vector space or a subspace but Linear Algebra is starting to look like foreign language for me. Can anyone help break this down and the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify that this subspace is closed under scalar multiplication and vector addition.

Since addition of matrices is done component-wise, any upper-triangular matrix sum will also be upper-triangular. (All that is needed is to note that the entries below the diagonal will consist of 0 + 0.)

Also, scalar multiplication applied to a matrix is distributed across each component. Since, a scalar times 0 produces zero, the entries below the diagonal will remain zero, and the result will remain upper-triangular.